# Running Standalone scripts Django

Tags: django

I am trying to learn, "How to run standalone scripts in django".
I am using python2.7 and django==1.4.3.
I have created a very basic script which i am trying to run but facing 
**import errors** . I don't want to create a management command as this is just 
temporary stuff and my focus is to learn also.

My Code

```
import os
import sys
from cartridge.shop.models import HomepageUpselling


class HomepageUpsellingToBestsellers():
    """This class copy the HomepageUpselling data to BestSellers"""

    def homepageuselling_to_bestsellers(self):
        """ Data Copy """
        hu_obj = HomepageUpselling.objects.all()
        for hu_iterable in hu_obj:
            bs_obj, created = \
                BestSeller.objects.get_or_create(product=hu_iterable.product,
                                                 variation=hu_iterable.variation)
            print "BestSeller data copying %s" % bs_obj.id
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.setttings")
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    hu_to_bs_obj = HomepageUpsellingToBestsellers()
    hu_to_bs_obj.homepageuselling_to_bestsellers()
    print "Data Copied"
```

Error

```
ImportError: No module named cartridge.shop.models
```

Comment: Is that in project folder or environment ?

Comment: I have created a directory called scripts with init file just next to parent folder. So parent folder is /Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/bhane.com and scripts directory is in  /Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/bhane.com/bhane/scripts

Comment: i think you need to setup django environment first

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it in my opinion (especially considering your usecase) is to write your own management command. Subclass `Basecommand` and then run it as

```
 python manage.py yourcommand arguments
```

[Django documentation for custom commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Django 1.4 So here is the right way to code environ ..

```
import os
import sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project_name.settings")

# you can import your model here and the locaion of function 
from your_project_name.models import Location

# From here you can start your script..
```

Comment: still the same :- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bhane/scripts/copy_homepageupselling_data_to_bestsellers.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cartridge.shop.models import HomepageUpselling
ImportError: No module named cartridge.shop.models

Comment: @djangobot https://stackoverflow.com/a/66446394/11590791 refer this code. It works fine.